# $J$-homomorphism and homotopy

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

We have Bott periodicity theorem for unitary group $U(n)$:
$$ \pi_{i-1}^{s}(U) = \pi_{i-1}(U(m)) \simeq \pi_{i}(Gr_m(\mathbb{C}^{2m})) \simeq \pi_{i+1}(SU(2m)) \simeq \pi_{i+1}^{s}(U) .$$
So we can define a complex $J$-homomorphism
$$ J:\pi_*(U) \rightarrow \pi^s_*  .$$
Can we use complex $J$-homomorphism in order to cauculate some stable (or instable) groups of spheres?